# About existence of Morse functions

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, morse-theory, cobordism

Let's consider 4-manifold $M$, $\partial M = \partial M_1 + \partial M_2 = S^1 \times S^2 + \mathbb{RP}^3$.
Is it true that there exist a Morse function $$f\colon M^4 \to [0,1],\quad f^{-1}(0) = \partial M_1 = S^1 \times S^2,\ f^{-1}(1) = \partial M_2 = \mathbb{RP}^3$$
with only one critical point of index 2.

Comment: Do you know anything about handlebodies? Index $k$ critical points correspond to attaching $k$-handles. The only real difference between the handlebody structures of $S^1 \times S^2$ and $\Bbb R P^3$ is how the $2$-handle is attached. You can geometrically cancel the $2$-handle of $S^1 \times S^2$ by attaching a $3$-handle, and then put in a single $2$-handle that gives $\Bbb R P^3$. So from this point of view, there should exist such a Morse function.

Comment: Looking at ASD's answer, I may have misinterpreted the question. Is $f$ supposed to have only one critical point total, and this single critical point is of index $2$? This is the assumption in ASD's answer. If $f$ can have several critical points, but only one of them can be of index $2$, then my comment applies (note that I assumed I could have an index $3$ critical point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is never true.

Attach a copy of $S^1 \times D^3$ to $M$ to get a 4-manifold with one boundary component, $\mathbb{RP}^3$.
If $M$ has a Morse function with one critical point of index two, this new manifold can be given a Morse function with three critical points with indices 0, 1 and 2. This means it is a rational ball, so the first and second Betti numbers are zero. The boundary of a rational ball has to have first homology of order $k^2$ for some $k$ (you can show this by messing about with exact sequences) and so it cannot be $\mathbb{RP}^3$.